# Angular2 chain http request

Tags: angular, http, observable

I have to make 2 http request. The first http request for return a list of url and some strings. Then I need to make another http request on this url to get anther data and append this data with the strings I got from the first http request.

How should I do this in angularJs2

Right now I can make the first http request using observable but I am stuck in getting the second http request.

I have been looking at observables,flatmap and mergemap, but I am new to both  angular2 and  observables and it is kind of confusion.

So my questions is what is the best way to chain this two request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is not specific to Angular, but mostly shows how to chain Reactive operators together to get what you need. You can do something like the following (warning: untested code):

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switch';

export class Foo {
    bar() {
        const httpClient: HttpClient = /* Your HTTP client here */;
        httpClient
            .get<UrlAndString[]>('first url')
            .map(urlsAndStrings => {
                const parameter = doSomethingWithUrlsAndStrings(urlsAndStrings);
                return httpClient
                    .get<SecondResult>(`second url?param=${parameter}`)
                    .map(secondResult => { return [urlsAndStrings, secondResult]; });
            })
            .switch()
            .subscribe(tuple => {
                console.log(tuple[0]); // The urls and strings, of type UrlAndString[].
                console.log(tuple[1]); // The second result, of type SecondResult.
            });
    }
}
```

The `import` statements bring in the [`map`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html) and [`switch`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/switch.html) operators so that you can chain them.

`map` transforms events as they come through, so you can see that when the first `.get()` returns something it will be mapped to another `Observable<T>`. So the type signature of the first `map` function will be `map<UrlAndString[], Observable<[UrlAndString[], SecondResult]>>`. Meaning it will return an `Observable<Observable<[UrlAndString[], SecondResult]>>`, or an `Observable` that publishes `Observable`s which publish tuples of type `UrlAndString[]` and `SecondResult`.

`switch` takes an `Observable<Observable<T>>` and turns it into an `Observable<T>`. The documentation I linked to above explains it better than I can. But you can see that the return type of that `.switch()` will be an `Observable<[UrlAndString[], SecondResult]>`.

The `.subscribe()` you're probably already familiar with.